# Getting a light brown screen while trying to run Google Maps in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am having an issue with a Google Map object in my app.

I am only modifying the latitude and longitude values on the code proposed by google, and the map which should be showing is just displaying a light brown screen with the Google logo in the bottom left corner.[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqk6O.jpg)

Can someone help me with this?

I am not even getting any error code in the Logcat and the app is running fine.

```
package com.app.chalanmx.Activities;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.app.chalanmx.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapServicio extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_servicio);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapServicio);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng torreon = new LatLng(25.53986916895781, -103.40568068906825);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(torreon).title("Torreon, Coah.").draggable(true));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(torreon));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already fixed this issue by adding my payment information to my Google account and activating the SDK in the google cloud console. If you have this same issue, please try that: add your billing information to the google account that you are using for this project and make sure you activated the SDK for maps in the google cloud platform. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added google maps API key in manifest?
If you haven't added API key add it in manifest inside `<application>` tag

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
   android:value="KEY" />
```

Otherwise If you have created a MapsActivity the android will automatically add this `<meta-data>` in manifest for you but you have to copy your API key inside `google_maps_api.xml` file under values folder

```
  <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">YOUR KEY</string>
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks. Yes, like you said I created a maps activity and the API key info was automatically added in the manifest. I also added the API key in the string of the google_maps_api.xml, but it's not working.